# Obtener lista de marcas de un objeto Json

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy necesitando crear un nuevo objeto con sólo algunos elementos de un objeto sin repetir, es decir:

Este es mi Objeto actual:

```
[
  {
    "id": 55,
    "title": "PICANTO",
    "marca": {
      "id": 13,
      "rendered": "KIA",
      "title": "KIA"
    },
    "modelo": "PICANTO",
    "combustible": "NAFTA",
    "capacidad": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "title": "VITZ",
    "marca": {
      "id": 11,
      "rendered": "TOYOTA",
      "title": "TOYOTA"
    },
    "modelo": "VITZ",
    "combustible": "NAFTA",
    "capacidad": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "title": "IST",
    "marca": {
      "id": 11,
      "rendered": "TOYOTA",
      "title": "TOYOTA"
    },
    "modelo": "IST",
    "combustible": "NAFTA",
    "capacidad": "3,4"
  }
]
```

Necesito obtener la lista de marcas sin repetir en un nuevo objeto:

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "title": "KIA"
  },
  {
      "id": 11,
      "title": "TOYOTA"
  }
]
```

Intenté de varias maneras pero no encuentro la solución:

this.marcas = this.vehiculos.flatMap(elem => elem.marca.map(i=>i.id));

Comment: La confusión que tienes es que `map` se utiliza sobre un arreglo y la propiedad `marca` no lo es.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo explicación en comentarios.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 55,
    "title": "PICANTO",
    "marca": {
      "id": 13,
      "rendered": "KIA",
      "title": "KIA"
    },
    "modelo": "PICANTO",
    "combustible": "NAFTA",
    "capacidad": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "title": "VITZ",
    "marca": {
      "id": 11,
      "rendered": "TOYOTA",
      "title": "TOYOTA"
    },
    "modelo": "VITZ",
    "combustible": "NAFTA",
    "capacidad": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "title": "IST",
    "marca": {
      "id": 11,
      "rendered": "TOYOTA",
      "title": "TOYOTA"
    },
    "modelo": "IST",
    "combustible": "NAFTA",
    "capacidad": "3,4"
  }
]

// diccionario para guardar los ids de las marcas que ya fueron filtradas
// esto se usa para eficiencia en la búsqueda
const existentes = {}
// la condicione del filtrado funciona así:
// !existentes[e.marca.id], se evalúa si el id de la marca no se encuentra en el diccionario
// si no está entonces la expresión es verdadera y se evalúa la siguiente
// (existentes[e.marca.id] = true) se ingresa el id al diccionario y se le asigna el valor true
// esta expresión siempre será verdadera cada vez que se evalúe y solo se evaluará en los casos
// en los que la condición anterior sea verdadera (esto se llama cortocircuito)
const filtrado = arr.filter(e => !existentes[e.marca.id] && (existentes[e.marca.id] = true))
const marcas = filtrado.map(e => e.marca)
console.log(marcas)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lobos!! De lujo tu resputa, tambié a @Mateo por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Mi opcion es menos funcional que la de @Lobos pero tambien puede servirte:

```js
let obj = [
  {
    "id": 55,
    "title": "PICANTO",
    "marca": {
      "id": 13,
      "rendered": "KIA",
      "title": "KIA"
    },
    "modelo": "PICANTO",
    "combustible": "NAFTA",
    "capacidad": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "title": "VITZ",
    "marca": {
      "id": 11,
      "rendered": "TOYOTA",
      "title": "TOYOTA"
    },
    "modelo": "VITZ",
    "combustible": "NAFTA",
    "capacidad": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "title": "IST",
    "marca": {
      "id": 11,
      "rendered": "TOYOTA",
      "title": "TOYOTA"
    },
    "modelo": "IST",
    "combustible": "NAFTA",
    "capacidad": "3,4"
  }
]

 const aux = [];
 const marcas = [];

 for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  if (!aux.includes(obj[i].marca.rendered)) {
   aux.push(obj[i].marca.rendered);
   marcas.push({"id":obj[i].id,"title": obj[i].marca.title})
  }
 }
 
 console.log(marcas);
```